# How can I send a signal to a program via external hardware

Tags: c#, hardware, software

I am trying to find a piece of hardware that will signal a program to start a timer when it is moving and stop when it stops. The hardware can just be a ball that moves and is connected to the computer through USB, I was thinking of something similar to the way a mouse would work. For the programing I would like to use c# or possibly ActionScript with adobe air. I am a web developer and have not had any experience with hardware or drivers and would appreciate any ideas on where to start. Maybe there is some piece of simple hardware out there that I can use to send signals to the computer or some literature of articles for beginners that you can point me to. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for "Arduino" and "Motion Sensors."

Comment: Why can't you use a mouse?

Comment: Because the mouse would need to be plugged in as well, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For USB I/O that you can interface with .NET, check out [Phidgets](http://www.phidgets.com/).  For instance, there are accelerometer [motion sensors](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=5) that connect directly over USB.  They have documentation about their .NET SDK on their site.  I've used it with success.

You could also just use a mouse, right?  :)

I also thought [this project on kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/supermechanical/twine-listen-to-your-world-talk-to-the-internet?ref=category) is similar to what you're describing, and wouldn't require any coding.

If you wanted to go wireless, consider buying a Wiimote and using the [wiimotelib](http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/) library written in C#.  You'll need a bluetooth connection on the PC.

If you have an Android phone, you could access the accelerometer and use that for motion detection.  You could use it in a tethered only mode... not sure how to interface it directly over the USB cable.  Alternatively it could be wireless over a WiFi connection.

Comment: The gadgeteer suite should interface well with C#, too.

Comment: The Phidgets look promising, I will look into it further tonight, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for a Digital USB-Module that you can directly address hardware via USB.

Comment: Please review the question again and be more specific in your answer.  As a new users you can benefit by reading the FAQ and guidelines like those at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer.  Questions and answer guidelines in the FAQ can help lead to higher reputation scores, and there is a badge for completely reading the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to suggest a solution without knowing exactly what it is you are trying to communicate with. There may be existing hardware that you can use, or you may need to create your own.

If there is an existing hardware that you can use, such as a mouse as a simple example, then all you need to do is communicate with the driver via it's API.

If you plan to make your own hardware, then depending on your budget, you may be able to create a custom device and create your own driver and API.

The easiest and most flexible option however, is to use an Arduino, or similar PIC product. An Arduino is a microcontroller, that can be used to interface with and control various sensors and input devices. You would create your custom sensors to detect the movement, and connect these to the arduino. You can then interface to the Arduino via a serial connection within a C# application on the PC.

See [www.arduino.cc](http://www.arduino.cc) for more information and lots of tutorials on how to use an Arduino.

Arduino's are great for experimenting or one of projects, but may not be suitable for a commercial product.

Comment: I think a mouse would work, I need to have a real mouse plugged in as well though to control the computer. Is it possible to change the way a mouse behaves, for example where it only communicates with my program and does not display on the computer screen.

Comment: @Christopher - if you right click on the second mouse in Device Manager, you can disable it.  I think you can probably still talk to it directly over USB from a C# program, but not sure.

Comment: Yea I was thinking more like reverse engineering it to just work that way without having to disable it every time, is that possible

Comment: @Christopher - if you're going to start taking apart a mouse, then consider buying an [FTDI chip breakout cable](http://www.robotshop.com/productinfo.aspx?pc=RB-Spa-431&lang=en-US) - they're the same cable used to program an Arduino and they're less than $20.  Using the free FTDI driver software from C#, you can read the digital I/O lines directly. If you wire 2 of them up to the optical sensors in an old style ball mouse, you should see pulses when the mouse moves.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will have to look more into that.